# Extract key value from string with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a function to extract key values from an string like this: **<!-- Name:Peter Smith --><!-- Age:23 -->**

I want to make an standard function to extract any value. The call is something like this: **var name=ExtractValue(text,"Name");**

This is my approach:

```
var text="<!-- Name:Peter Smith --><!-- Age:23 -->"; // Data to be scanned

var name=ExtractValue(text,"Name"); // Get the "Name" key value
var age=ExtractValue(text,"Age");   // Get the "Age" key value
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Extracted name: ("+name+"), age: ("+age+")";

// Function for extranting key values
function ExtractValue(data,key){
    // It's try to be like /Name:(.*)\s--/
    var rx = "/"+key+"(.*)\s--/";
    var values = rx.exec(data);
    if(values.lenght>0){
        return values[1];
    } else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Here's an example how to create a Regex that support similar data format:
https://regex101.com/r/euwxBp/1

Since you're in JavaScript land, I'd convert the data to to an object, for its native key-value support, and then lookup 'keys' by getting the obj[key] ref and checking if it exists.

P.S. - You haven't mentioned what key and data formats should be supported - so the Regex is pretty basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var text="<!-- Name:Peter Smith --><!-- Age:23 -->"; // Data to be scanned

var name=ExtractValue(text,"Name"); // Get the "Name" key value
var age=ExtractValue(text,"Age");   // Get the "Age" key value
console.log("Extracted name: ("+name+"), age: ("+age+")");

function ExtractValue(data,key){
    var rx = new RegExp(key + ":(.*?)\\s+--");
    var values = rx.exec(data); // or: data.match(rx);
    return values && values[1];
}
```

Don't forget to escape backslashes in a string literal. So `"\\s"` instead of `"\s"`, as the latter would be exactly the same as `"s"`. Also, the colon was missing in your regular expression. Finally, you had a spelling mistake in the `length` property name, so your `if` condition would always be false.

Be aware that `exec` and `match`  will return `null` when there is no match, so you should not assume there is a `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

This approach returns an object with all the found key/value pairs. From there, you can search for any key you want.

```js
var text = "<!-- Name:Peter Smith --><!-- Age:23 --><!-- Key with  space  : yes -->";

var data = ExtractData(text);
console.log(data);
console.log("Extracted name: (" + data["Name"] + "), age: (" + data["Age"] + ")");

function ExtractData(data) {
  var matches = data.match(/([A-Za-z\s]+:[^\-\-\>]+)/g);
  var data = {};

  if (Array.isArray(matches)) {
    matches.forEach(function(match) {
      var pair = match.split(":");
      if (pair.length === 2) {
        data[pair[0].trim()] = pair[1].trim();
      }
    });
  }

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex, you can use string split function.

```
var text = "<!-- Name:Peter Smith --><!-- Age:23 -->"; // Data to be scanned
var obj = ExtractToObj(text);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Extracted name: (" + obj["Name"] + "), age: (" + obj["Age"] + ")";

function ExtractToObj(data) {
  var obj = {};
  var kvps = data.split("-->").filter(function(n) {
    return n !== ""; // remove empty elements
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < kvps.length; i++) {
    var kvp = kvps[i].split(":");
    var key = kvp[0].replace("<!--", "").trim();
    var value = kvp[1].trim();
    obj[key] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ydjbc4yq/

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```js
const data = `<div><!-- Name   : Peter Smith --><!-- Age:23 -->some test data that is not found</div>`

const getData = data => {
  const obj = {}, regex = /<!--\s*(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*-->/g
  let temp
  while (temp = regex.exec(data)){
    obj[temp[1]] = temp[2]
  }
  return obj
}

const personInfo = getData(data)
console.log(`Extracted name: (${personInfo.Name}), age: (${personInfo.Age})`)
```

Or if you want to extract only one property:

```js
const data = `<div><!-- Name   : Peter Smith --><!-- Age:23 -->some test data that is not found</div>`

const getData = (data, key) => (data.match(new RegExp(`<!--\\s*${key}\\s*:\\s*(.*?)\\s*-->`)) || [, null])[1]

console.log(`${getData(data, 'Name')}`)
```